# How do I use product formula within if else condition?

Tags: excel-formula

```
A1       B1   C1    D1     E1    F1

Maths    5   44    High    ?     ?
```

1. I want to display the formula in `E1`
2. corresponding result in `F1` cell.

scenario is if `A1` cell is 'maths' and `D1` cell is 'High' then I want to multiply `B1` value with `7 (B1*7)` otherwise `(B1*10)è

```
if(AND(A1="Maths",D1="High") product(B1*7))
```

I'm trying to use the product formula within if condition like above. But I'm getting error message. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood you right: if the String "Maths" is in the A1 cell AND the String "High" is in the D1 Cell, you want to procude the product of B1*7;
if the String "Maths" is not in the A1 cell OR the String "High" is not in the D1 cell, you want to produce the product of B1*10;

well you could use the following attempt:

```
  =IF(AND(A1="Maths";D1="High");PRODUCT(B1*7);PRODUCT(B1*10))
```

If you want to split the products in the specific way, that the Product PRODUCT(B1*7) is in the E1 cell, and the Product PRODUCT(B1*10) is in the F1 cell, you could use the following code:

```
E1  =IF(AND(A1="Maths";D1="High");PRODUCT(B1*7);"No result")
F1  =IF(AND(A1="Maths";D1="High");"No result";PRODUCT(B1*10))
```

Comment: I have used it in my excel,its working fine thank u. but its not accepting semicolon ';' so i used coma ','

Answer (score 0):

the formula I would use in your example would be

```
=PRODUCT(B1,IF(AND(A1="Maths",D1="High"),7,10))
```

to display the formula, there are 3 options, depending on the version of excel.

In excel 2013, you can use `=FORMULATEXT(F1)` [msdn](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/formulatext-function-HA102753280.aspx)
In previous versions, you could either copy the formula, then put a single quote mark in front of the formula, or you could create a UDF (which would then work the same way as the Excel 2013 version.
(UDF Code:

```
Function GetFormula(CellRef as Range) as String
   GetFormula = CellRef.Formula
End Function
```

), and use `=GetFormula(F1)`

Comment: You can also press ctrl+tilde.

Comment: Can u tell me where can i use this getformula function in vba? i have tried its not working for me...